Can you identify the thriller about babysitting please?
Thriller movie
I watched it online last year and can't find it. It is most likely American and came out in the last five years. It is about a young brown haired teenage girl who gets hired to be a babysitter. She builds a 'relationship' with the dad and I remember one part where shows the daughter she is babysitting scars she has. The movie is also based around cameras the parents set up in a bear (babysitting cam). 

Nanny Cam (2014)

Linda has a seemingly perfect marriage with her rugged and handsome
  husband Mark and an adorable 8 year old daughter, Chloe. But when
  Chloe is injured by an elderly babysitter who has slipped into
  dementia, Linda wants to ensure that her child is never hurt again.
  Initially, Heather, the new babysitter, seems like the ideal addition
  to this practically perfect family. But Heather is a schemer who
  exploits the cracks in Mark and Linda's relationship. As Linda later
  learns, to her horror, Heather's intentions go far beyond the
  mischievous.




